# I need to record the data changes on a Cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The following code creates a change log sheet to track the changes that my team does in each cell in Google Sheets.

**Question**

How do I add the "name of the editor or his Email" to this change log?

```
function onEdit() {

  // This script records changes to the spreadsheet on a "Changelog" sheet.

  // The change log includes:

 // "Timestamp", "Sheet name", "Cell address", "Column label", "Row label", "Value entered"

  var sheetsToWatch = ['outcome overview', 'Sheet1', 'Another sheet'];

 // name of the sheet where the changelog is stored

  var changelogSheetName = "Changelog";

  var timestamp = new Date();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();

  // if it is the change log sheet that is being edited, do not record the change

 if (sheetName == changelogSheetName) return;

  // if the sheet name does not appear in sheetsToWatch, do not record the change

  var matchFound = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < sheetsToWatch.length; i++) {

  if (sheetName.match(sheetsToWatch[i])) matchFound = true;

  }

 if (!matchFound) return;

  var columnLabel = sheet.getRange(/* row 1 */ 1, cell.getColumn()).getValue();
  var rowLabel = sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(), /* column A */ 1).getValue();

  var changelogSheet = ss.getSheetByName(changelogSheetName);

 if (!changelogSheet) {

 // no changelog sheet found, create it as the last sheet in the spreadsheet
    changelogSheet = ss.insertSheet(changelogSheetName, ss.getNumSheets());

   // Utilities.sleep(2000); // give time for the new sheet to render before 

going back
    // ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
    changelogSheet.appendRow(["Timestamp", "Sheet name", "Cell address", "Column 

label", "Row label", "Value entered"]);
    changelogSheet.setFrozenRows(1);
  }
  changelogSheet.appendRow([timestamp, sheetName, cell.getA1Notation(), columnLabel, rowLabel, cell.getValue()]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run onEdit as an installable trigger rather than a simple trigger. Under edit, there is 'current project triggers'. Set your onEdit. Once you do that, it will ask for your permissions that will give access to user's details. If you run onEdit as simple trigger, it does not have access to user's details.

Edit the following lines

```
changelogSheet.appendRow(["Email","Timestamp", "Sheet name", "Cell address", "Column label", "Row label", "Value entered"]);

changelogSheet.appendRow([Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), timestamp, sheetName, cell.getA1Notation(), columnLabel, rowLabel, cell.getValue()]);
```

For more details check https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: that worked perfectly with the exception that i had to make the changeLog Sheet editable, to solve this i got this code that creates a helper sheet to track the old data and keep it from being changed but it is also an onEdit function and i am unable to make them both working together, can  you help, i'll post the code as an answer

Comment: Instead of having them work together and making sure both are in sync, why not just keep only the editable sheet?

Comment: because then i cant relay on the Change log sheet as any user can manipulate the data after it is logged (so the change log is practically useless)

Comment: thank you for your fast responce, so can it be done ?

Comment: I am not perfectly clear as to what you need. Why would any user be able to edit your sheet. Only those users with whom you have shared the sheet would be able to change it, right?

Comment: well we are a team who are filling data, they all have access to change the mainSheet and log new data, now this other sheet (the changeLog sheet) i want to give them access so the code log their changes to each cell in the main sheet, if i block users access from the changeLog sheet the code wont be able to log the changes in each cell in the main sheet... i hope it is clear

Answer (score 1):

the modifications that i made with your remarks could only work if i un-protect the sheet (changeLog) so the code can log every user's change, so i got This script to prevents cells from being updated. When a user edits a cell on the master sheet, it is checked against the same cell on a helper sheet. If the value on the helper sheet is empty, the new value is stored on both sheets.If the value on the helper sheet is not empty, it is copied to the cell on the master sheet, effectively undoing the change (to protect the data already entered)

the question: this code is also onEdit function and it is not working with the old onEdit code, how can i join then in the same onEdit function?

P.s i have already created the Helper sheet by duplicating the Changelog sheet and named it Helper

the new Code:

```
function onEdit() {


  var masterSheetName = "Changelog" // sheet where the cells are protected from updates
  var helperSheetName = "Helper" // sheet where the values are copied for later checking
  var firstDataRow = 1; // only take into account edits on or below this row
  var firstDataColumn = 1; // only take into account edits on or to the right of this column

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var masterSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if (masterSheet.getName() != masterSheetName) return;

  var masterCell = masterSheet.getActiveCell();
  if (masterCell.getRow() < firstDataRow || masterCell.getColumn() < firstDataColumn) return;

  var helperSheet = ss.getSheetByName(helperSheetName);
  var helperCell = helperSheet.getRange(masterCell.getA1Notation());
  var newValue = masterCell.getValue();
  var oldValue = helperCell.getValue();

  if (oldValue == "") {
    helperCell.setValue(newValue);
  } else {
    masterCell.setValue(oldValue);
  }
}
```

the 1st code after your recommendation is as follows:

```
function onEdit() {
  // This script records changes to the spreadsheet on a "Changelog" sheet.
  // The changelog includes these columns:
  // "Timestamp", "Sheet name", "Cell address", "Column label", "Row label", "Value entered"

  var sheetsToWatch = ['Sheet1', 'add more'];
  // name of the sheet where the changelog is stored
  var changelogSheetName = "Changelog";

  var timestamp = new Date();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();

  // if it is the changelog sheet that is being edited, do not record the change
  if (sheetName == changelogSheetName) return;

  // if the sheet name does not appear in sheetsToWatch, do not record the change
  var matchFound = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < sheetsToWatch.length; i++) {
   if (sheetName.match(sheetsToWatch[i])) matchFound = true;
  }
  if (!matchFound) return;

  var columnLabel = sheet.getRange(/* row 3 */ 3, cell.getColumn()).getValue();
  var rowLabel = sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(), /* column B */ 2).getValue();

  var changelogSheet = ss.getSheetByName(changelogSheetName);
  if (!changelogSheet) {
    // no changelog sheet found, create it as the last sheet in the spreadsheet
    changelogSheet = ss.insertSheet(changelogSheetName, ss.getNumSheets());
    // Utilities.sleep(2000); // give time for the new sheet to render before going back
    // ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
    changelogSheet.appendRow(["Email","Timestamp", "Sheet name", "Cell address", "Column label", "Row label", "Value entered"]);
    changelogSheet.setFrozenRows(1);
  }
  changelogSheet.appendRow([Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), timestamp, sheetName, cell.getA1Notation(), columnLabel, rowLabel, cell.getValue()]);
}
```