# Record the data changes on a column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47966175/i-need-to-record-the-data-changes-on-a-cell-in-google-sheets) this code to record changes to cells in google sheets, which has been really useful but I was wondering if it can be modified to register only changes in specific column rather than the whole sheet.

**Code I found:**

```
function onEdit() {
  // This script records changes to the spreadsheet on a "Changelog" sheet.
  // The changelog includes these columns:
  // "Timestamp", "Sheet name", "Cell address", "Column label", "Row label", "Value entered"

  var sheetsToWatch = ['Sheet1', 'add more'];
  // name of the sheet where the changelog is stored
  var changelogSheetName = "Changelog";

  var timestamp = new Date();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();

  // if it is the changelog sheet that is being edited, do not record the change
  if (sheetName == changelogSheetName) return;

  // if the sheet name does not appear in sheetsToWatch, do not record the change
  var matchFound = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < sheetsToWatch.length; i++) {
   if (sheetName.match(sheetsToWatch[i])) matchFound = true;
  }
  if (!matchFound) return;

  var columnLabel = sheet.getRange(/* row 3 */ 3, cell.getColumn()).getValue();
  var rowLabel = sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(), /* column B */ 2).getValue();

  var changelogSheet = ss.getSheetByName(changelogSheetName);
  if (!changelogSheet) {
    // no changelog sheet found, create it as the last sheet in the spreadsheet
    changelogSheet = ss.insertSheet(changelogSheetName, ss.getNumSheets());
    // Utilities.sleep(2000); // give time for the new sheet to render before going back
    // ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
    changelogSheet.appendRow(["Email","Timestamp", "Sheet name", "Cell address", "Column label", "Row label", "Value entered"]);
    changelogSheet.setFrozenRows(1);
  }
  changelogSheet.appendRow([Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), timestamp, sheetName, cell.getA1Notation(), columnLabel, rowLabel, cell.getValue()]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a condition as follows:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var colToWatch = 2
  if(e.range.getColumn() == colToWatch) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

So final state of your code is:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // This script records changes to the spreadsheet on a "Changelog" sheet.
  // The changelog includes these columns:
  // "Timestamp", "Sheet name", "Cell address", "Column label", "Row label", "Value entered"
 
  var sheetsToWatch = ['Sheet1', 'add more'];
  // name of the sheet where the changelog is stored
  var changelogSheetName = "Changelog";

  var timestamp = new Date();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();

  // if it is the changelog sheet that is being edited, do not record the change
  if (sheetName == changelogSheetName) return;

  // if the sheet name does not appear in sheetsToWatch, do not record the change
  var matchFound = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < sheetsToWatch.length; i++) {
    if (sheetName.match(sheetsToWatch[i])) matchFound = true;
  }
  if (!matchFound) return;
  
  var colToWatch = 2; //you can change this column index
  if (event.range.getColumn() == colToWatch) {
    var columnLabel = sheet.getRange( /* row 3 */ 3, cell.getColumn()).getValue();
    var rowLabel = sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(), /* column B */ 2).getValue();

    var changelogSheet = ss.getSheetByName(changelogSheetName);
    if (!changelogSheet) {
      // no changelog sheet found, create it as the last sheet in the spreadsheet
      changelogSheet = ss.insertSheet(changelogSheetName, ss.getNumSheets());
      // Utilities.sleep(2000); // give time for the new sheet to render before going back
      // ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
      changelogSheet.appendRow(["Email", "Timestamp", "Sheet name", "Cell address", "Column label", "Row label", "Value entered"]);
      changelogSheet.setFrozenRows(1);
    }
    changelogSheet.appendRow([Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), timestamp, sheetName, cell.getA1Notation(), columnLabel, rowLabel, cell.getValue()])
  }
}
```

Comment: @Nicolas_C00 Since this `onEdit` function is a trigger, it will run automatically when you edit a cell in 2nd column.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is solid, however you might want to take into consideration if your range includes multiple columns. Here's some options:

**Run Code Only When Edits Are Exclusively In A Certain Column**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const theColumn = 2;
  var range = e.range;
  if(theColumn===range.getColumn()&&theColumn===range.getLastColumn()){
      //Run your code.
    }
}
```

**Run code if edit includes the column, along with other columns (i.e. deleting the entire spreadsheet.**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const theColumn = 2;
  var range = e.range;
  if (theColumn >= range.getColumn() && theColumn <= range.getLastColumn()) {
    //do something
  }
}
```